# Align ul with img

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am trying to get my links in a `ul` to align with the image and text so I can have a good navbar, but for some reason it goes below everything. How can I fix this?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#tagline {
  font-style: italic;
}

nav {
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 7px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 7px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 7px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

#logo {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

li,
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/qiu818fhr/lb_logo.png" id="logo" alt="logo">
  <span id="tagline">Live, 1-to-1, flexible and personalized</span>
  <ul id="nav-items">
    <li><a href="#">How it Works</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Teachers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Enroll</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

apply `display:flex` to `nav` and why not removing `float:right` from `li` as well?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#tagline {
  font-style: italic;
}

nav {
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 7px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 7px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 7px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#logo {
  padding: 10px;
}

ul {
  margin-left: auto;
}

li,
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: black;
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/qiu818fhr/lb_logo.png" id="logo" alt="logo">
  <span id="tagline">Live, 1-to-1, flexible and personalized</span>
  <ul id="nav-items">
    <li><a href="#">How it Works</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Teachers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Enroll</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: The image isn't aligned with the text now.

Comment: what you mean? did you see my snippet? did you use `align-items:center` as in my answer?

Comment: @HarambeSquad you just need to work your `nav`s `padding` or `height` to fix that,

Answer (score 0):

You want to float the `#nav-items` list right, since that's a block element. Then `display: inline-block` on the `li`'s, and `color`/`text-decoration` on the `a`'s

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#tagline {
  font-style: italic;
}

nav {
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 7px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 7px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 7px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

#logo {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#nav-items {
  float: right;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>LanguageBird</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>

  <nav>
    <img src="img/lb_logo.png" id="logo" alt="logo">
    <span id="tagline">Live, 1-to-1, flexible and personalized</span>
    <ul id="nav-items">
      <li><a href="#">How it Works</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Teachers</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Enroll</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

If you want to use a flex layout, apply `display: flex;` to `nav`, and use `align-items` to center vertically. Then assign `margin-left: auto` to `#nav-items` to push that menu to the right.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#tagline {
  font-style: italic;
}

nav {
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 7px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 7px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 7px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

#logo {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#nav-items {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/qiu818fhr/lb_logo.png" id="logo" alt="logo">
  <span id="tagline">Live, 1-to-1, flexible and personalized</span>
  <ul id="nav-items">
    <li><a href="#">How it Works</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Teachers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Enroll</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```